# Overriding get() method in models

Tags: django, django-models

Am trying to override get() method in my view as :

```
broadcast = Broadcast.objects.get(request, pk = broadcast_id)
```

In my model am overriding method as :

```
class Broadcast(models.Model):      
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=300 , verbose_name = 'Say it out loud !')
    .
    .

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user == self.person :
            super(Broadcast, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        else :
            return none
```

Two questions ->
Where am I going wrong with the overriding?
How do I access the "request" argument passed into get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`get` isn't a method on the model - you access it via `objects`, so it's a method on the Manager. See the [official Manager documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/).

The way you have defined the method signature, the request is available as `args[0]`.

Comment: So how do I override the Manager's method get ?

Comment: Er, by defining a custom Manager subclass with an overridden get method, as shown in that documentation...

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation you refer to does not have an explicit example of an overridden `get` method.

Answer (score 22):

Given the poll app example in the Django tutorial. You can perform a `get` operation to fetch poll
questions from the database.

```
In : Question.objects.get(pk=1)
Out: <Question: Question object>
```

This blog post shows how to override that method. It is not on the model itself. `Question.objects`
gives you the manager.

```
In : Question.objects
Out: <django.db.models.manager.Manager at 0x10d3b8860>
```

You can drop in a custom manager in your models.py.

```
class QuestionManager(models.Manager):
    pass

class Question(models.Model):
    objects = QuestionManager()
```

which results in...

```
In : Question.objects
Out: <app.models.QuestionManager at 0x107456e48>
```

But we are not quite there yet. Question.objects.get is doing some delegation magic and actually
calling get on an instance of QuerySet. We can replace

```
class QuestionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        print('hello world')
        return super().get(**kwargs)

class QuestionManager(models.Manager.from_queryset(QuestionQuerySet)):
    pass
```

Voilà!

```
In : Question.objects.get(pk=1)
hello world
Out: <Question: Question object>
```

References:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get

Answer (score 1):

Note that more modern Django versions (since 1.7), provide an easier way to do this.  Check out the `as_manager()` QuerySet method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods