# Django Fallback to model lookup from external API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST framework to serve up JSON content for a website front end. On the back end, I have two Django models, Player and Match, that each reference multiple of the other. A Match contains multiple Players, and a Player contains multiple Matches. This data is originally retrieved from a third-party API.

Matches and Players must be fetched separately from the API, and can only be fetched one at a time. When an object is fetched, its data is converted from the external JSON format into my Django model. At this point, the Match/Player will live forever in Django. The hard part is that I want this external fetching to be seamless. If I query for a player or match and it's in the DB, then just serve what we have there. Otherwise, I want to fetch that object from the external DB.

My question is, does Django provide any convenient way of handling this? Ideally, any query along the lines of `Match.objects.get(id=...)` will handle this API fallback transparently (I don't mind the fact that this query may take significantly longer in some cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a way is "convenient" depends on your expectations ...

You could create a custom QuerySet where you override the `get()` method to include your fetch-from-API logic. Then you create a custom manager based on that QuerySet, like the docs show [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods).
Finally add that custom manager to your model.

See also [this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520445/overriding-get-method-in-models).

Comment: Thank you! I will read through that documentation and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Did this help you? Could you get it working? If so, I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I ended making a new manager and queryset, and overriding get.